# ViewModel Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCart(int phoneListingID, string sellerSKU)
{
    ShoppingBasket shoppingBasket = new ShoppingBasket();
    BasketItem currentItem = new BasketItem
    {
        sellerID = 1,
        Price = 100,
        Quantity = 1,
        sellerSKU = "testsku"
    };

    shoppingBasket.AddtoBasket(currentItem, this.HttpContext);

    var viewModel = new BasketViewModel
    {
        basketItems = ShoppingBasket.GetBasketItems(this.HttpContext),
        basketTotal = ShoppingBasket.GetBasketTotal(this.HttpContext)
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

My form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart","ShoppingBasket",new { phoneListingID = 12345, sellerSKU = "test"}, FormMethod.Post ))    
{   
    <input type="submit" value="AddToCart" />
}
```

The expected result is that my BasketViewModel page is returned, however the view being returned is `ShoppingBasket/AddToCart?PhoneID=xxxx&sellerSKU=xxxx`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVC Suppose your action is like

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    return View();
}
```

In this scenerio it will point to the view named 'MyAction'. If you want to send it to another view make it like

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    return View("MyViewName");
}
```

If you want to pass some model to make it like

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    return View("MyViewName",model); // Here model is your object of model class
}
```

In you snippet your are returning default i.e. 'AddToCart' view because you are not describing explicitly. Make your code like

```
return View("BasketViewModel",viewModel); // where BasketViewModel is your view name
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning that controller's View, if you wish to transfer to another view try 
`return BasketViewActionResult(viewmodel)`

Then access your 'BasketViewActionResult'

```
Function BasketViewActionResult(model as BasketViewModel) as ActionResult
 return View(model)
End Function
```

Sorry if you don't get VB, I can translate it to C# for you if you wish.

Edit:
You can also simply change the form's action.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("BasketView","ShoppingBasket",...
```

and make all your manipulations within that actionresult